# htaccess with %{QUERY_STRING} and %{HTTP_REFERER} to preserve query var

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a wordpress site that has two different versions. a prop site and a nonprop site.

The prop site is accessible by going to http://example.com/?prop=1. Once in the site, I need any internal links to maintain the prop query variable. I want to do this with a query var and not a session var or cookie because at any point, a user should be able to take out prop=1 from the url to access the regular site. But as long as a user is in the prop site, any link they click should preserve that prop variable.

So if they're at example.com/?prop=1 and click on a link for example.com/help, they will be brought to example.com/help?prop=1

I don't know much about htaccess rules, but here is what I have so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^prop=1.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://amex/hello/$1 [L,R]
```

This doesn't work, but essentially, I want to check if the query exists in the referring url, and carry it over to wherever they were trying to go. Also looking into something like this with QUERY_STRING, but can't really figure it out

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prop=1$ [NC]
```

Comment: Def a good reason to use session (I know you want to avoid). I have hacked .htacces a lot, but I am far from the authority, so here are some spitball thoughts. 

.htaccess is pretty "dumb", besides some PHP ini type stuff you can tweak, generally this file is part of a mod_rewrite schema taking request info and rewriting (broad stroke). So your desire to rewrite is possible, but I can't think of any way for the server/.htaccess to know that ?prop=1 is in effect w/out cookie and/or session (persistence). I would love some insight. Can .htaccess read $_REQUEST?

Comment: i'm thinking of dumbing it down so the server doesn't really need to "know" - whenever a new page is loaded, i want to check if the URL it came from (%{HTTP_REFERER}) had the query var in it, and if it did, append that to the end of the current URL

Comment: Your request is not unreasonable, but it is a little ```qwurky```. Jon Lin's answer might be exactly what you are looking for - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below the `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !prop=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (^|&)prop=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?prop=%2 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: just threw this in. unfortunately, when I am at example.com/?prop=1 and click on a link like example.com/posts, it doesn't keep the prop var.

Comment: could you explain your second rewrite rule with %{HTTP_REFERER} and the rule at the end? I'm assuming $1 is the incoming url?